# Вывод превью изображения через phpthumbon MODX Revo

Tags: modx

Всем привет. Пытаюсь на главной вывести превью новости (картинка, заголовок и описание).
Это на главной

```html
[[!getPage? &element=`getResources` &parents=`2` &tpl=`articleTpl` &limit=`3` &includeTVs=`1` &sortby=`{"publishedon":"DESC"}`]]
```

Это сам шаблон

```html
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="single_property">
                        <div class="property_thumb">
                            <div class="property_tag">
                                    For Sale
                            </div>
                            <img src="[[+tv.img:phpthumbof]]" alt="[[+longtitle]]">
                        </div>
                        <div class="property_content">
                            <div class="main_pro">
                                    <h3><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+longtitle]]</a></h3>
                                    <div class="mark_pro">
                                        <img src="img/svg_icon/location.svg" alt="">
                                        <span>[[+introtext]]</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="amount">From $20k</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer_pro">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single_info_doc">
                                            <img src="img/svg_icon/square.svg" alt="">
                                            <span>1200 Sqft</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single_info_doc">
                                            <img src="img/svg_icon/bed.svg" alt="">
                                            <span>2 Bed</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="single_info_doc">
                                            <img src="img/svg_icon/bath.svg" alt="">
                                            <span>2 Bath</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Картинка не выводится, в консоли выводит так

```html
<img src=(unknown) alt="Расширенный">
```

Подскажите, куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. убедитесь, что вывод [[+tv.img]] непуст и содержит путь к изображению
2. для phpthumbof укажите больше параметров обработки, например, ширину и длину:
   [[tv.img:phpthumbof=`w=120&h=120`]]
3. Справка: https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/phpthumbof/index#usage-examples

Comment: 1. Изображение выводится так — [[+tv.img]]
2. Даже если указать больше параметров, ничего не выходит.

Comment: Не знаю, что случилось, вот так выводит [[+tv.img:phpthumbof]]